# In android I am posting xml data to server but getting 403 error

Tags: android

I need to verify a user by making a post request. I am posting my xml data using using REST protocol but getting 403 error. Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong, below is my code to post.

```
public void makePostConnection(String fileUrl,
            HashMap<String, String> requestData) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            url = new URL(fileUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(fileUrl);
            httppost.addHeader("accept", "text/xml");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    requestData.size());
            System.out.println("Size= " + requestData.size());

            for (Entry<String, String> entry : requestData.entrySet()) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry
                        .getValue()));
                System.out.println("Key= " + entry.getKey() + " Value= "
                        + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("Request ba= " + nameValuePairs.toString());
            StringEntity requestBody = new StringEntity(
                    nameValuePairs.toString());
            // requestBody.setContentType("text/xml");
            // httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setEntity(requestBody);
            // httppost.set
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("Code= " + code);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 403 errors means it is an authentication problem. Does the server need authentication?

Comment: Exactly My server needs an authentication token I am getting it and making my request body like this: [token=bEZ9C61PLg56yz81LM1yo9S, imeino=12345676543456543234, emailid=gh@gmail.com, mobileno=1447525863]

Comment: Check with the sever if those are sufficient to authenticate..

Comment: if server was ok it will not give as response 403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi I solve my problem by changing some line I set 
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
and make a urlencoded request by doing this
UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8);
Below is my all code to make a successful request.

```
try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(fileUrl);
            httppost.addHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    requestData.size());
            System.out.println("Size= " + requestData.size());

            for (Entry<String, String> entry : requestData.entrySet()) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry
                        .getValue()));
                System.out.println("Key= " + entry.getKey() + " Value= "
                        + entry.getValue());
            }

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                    HTTP.UTF_8);
            httppost.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            System.out.println("Code= " + code);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```